# Best Way to Add Object Via Other Class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

In my iPhone app, I have a custom `UIViewController` class setup which adds some `UIImageView`s and things.

How can I access this class via my main `UIViewController` and, for example, call a method from that outside class and have it add those `UIImageView`s to the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make property and public methods, after that you can call them in target viewcontroller.

p.s. But I never used this approach because it breaks controller's logic. Instead of I usually use some managers which has all required methods. (DBManager, NetworkManager, etc)